# Generate a redistributable project with CMake

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake

I'm looking for generating a redistributable project for Windows and Linux using CMake as project configuration system and gcc-4.8 / VS2012, plus extra thirdparty libraries like Qt5. How can i create a package with all the needed dependencies and make the project running on other machines, without installing on those machines the required packages (i.e. Qt5 setup)?

**EDIT**

Googling **heavily** i've found Qt5 requires some files and i've found this discussion 
[Application deployed with QT5 libraries does not start on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144075/application-deployed-with-qt5-libraries-does-not-start-on-windows-7)

which explains the required Qt5 dependencies.

Comment: On windows I do this with my CMake based projects in my CMakeLists.txt scripts. I mean I have a script that bundles the correct microsoft redistributable and I also have cmake scripts that collect a list of every dependent dll. With this list I add these to components in my cpack settings that generate a nsis installer. With that said CMake has a bundleutilities module that can do some of this for you without the need to write scripts. Since I have already developed my scripts years ago I leave it as it is..

Comment: @drescherjm: could you share this script?

Comment: I will see what I can do. The scripts contains a few macros that are not well described so I will have to document this.

Comment: @drescherjm: Perhaps the InstallRequiredSystemLibraries module of CMake can be useful for the microsoft redist? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13579615/417197

Comment: @Andre with my script, I'm already able to extract the microsoft redist: in fact, i have in my "Install" folder the msvcp110.dll and the msvcr110.dll. What I'm trying to solve is the final validation of the executable and the final packaging

Comment: @Andre For the redistributable I am doing what you describe as the alternative to InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.

Comment: @blackibiza looking at the source code for BundleUtilities.cmake it looks to me that there should be more info printed above the error you posted. Is that all? You may have to modify (adding additional output) BundleUtilities.cmake to debug why it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would use [`install`](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake%3aInstall_Commands) to list the desired files and [`CPack`](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake%3aPackaging_With_CPack) for packaging them. That is, suppose I'd like to create a package consisting of the following components:

- `my_nifty_library.dll`
- `my_nifty_executable.exe`
- `QtCore.dll`
- `QtGUI.dll`

(Disclaimer: I'm not Qt expert so the last two files might not exist at all, but you get the idea.)

Given that both `my_nifty_library` and `my_nifty_executable` are part of your project, you have control over them, so simply do the following:

```
install(TARGETS my_nifty_library my_nifty_executable
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

Now, since Qt won't be built as part of your project, I suggest you use the [`ExternalProject`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject) module.

Now, you can use `CPack` and create, say, a NSIS installer or a `tar.gz` out of the installed files.